# Can you use robocopy to copy changes in an encrypted veracrypt container?

Tags: encryption, robocopy

I want to create a batch file to backup a encrypted container that is saved in multiple places, but when I make a change and try to copy it using robocopy, it never copies it to the other encrypted containers in different locations.

Comment: What `robocopy` command are you using? What do you mean it's saved in multiple places? What do you mean by other encrypted containers in other locations? What is happening and what would you expect to happen?

Comment: robocopy source destination /COPY:DATS /MIR /EFSRAW /R:2 /W:0 /E /ETA. my encrypted container is on my D drive E drive which is a usb flash device and my G drive which is where I keep my documents. I mount the encrypted veracrypt file and then I make a change to its contents. Then I unmount and try to backup the other two unmounted encrypted files located in the other drives from the first and it doesn't work

Comment: Please don't include such information in a comment but rather add it to your original question. It can be vital information after all. Rather than "backup" you're simply trying to overwrite those files. Do you get any errors using the copy command? The `/MIR` flag doesn't exactly look useful if you're only copying a single file. You probably don't need the `/EFSRAW` flag as well as it's not a Windows encrypted file. The `/E` seems to be pretty similar to `/MIR` (they might actually be exclusive?) and again shouldn't be needed with a single file.